# Georeferencing PNG with transparency via gdal produce "green pixels" in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, gdal-translate, shaded-relief

This is just intriguing while not blocking my way, but I wonder what is going on and would like to get feedbacks from more experienced users.

**1) Given [a trans.png](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Yug-trans.png) file** (1.1MB) looks good and conserve transparencies (Stackexchanges displays below an altered version as .jpg) :

[image]

**2) I restore georeferencing** using :

```
gdal_translate -a_ullr 67.0 37.5 99.0 27.0 -co COMPRESS=LZW  -co ALPHA=YES       ./trans.png ./trans.gis.tif
```

**3) The output trans.gis.tif** (1.6MB) looks good and conserve transparencies (Stackexchanges displays below an altered version as .jpg):

[image]

**4) Loading it in Quantum GIS**, it get well positionned (georeferencing works!), but the image is ill colored with the darkest areas (and only them!) becoming green :

[image]

**Is this green artifact normal ? How to fix it (so I may see the expected black pixels) ?**

---

Edit: file added in 1)

Comment: Can you add the `style` tab of the layers properties? Setting the extent from 2%/98% to `exact full` might help.

Comment: @AndreJ: I added in 1) a link toward the source png for testing.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the source file is a one-band file, which is transformed into a 3-band tif file. You can improve that using `-expand rgba` in the gdal_translate command.

---

**EDIT**

Looking into the downloadable file you offer, it has two bands: one gray and one alpha. QGIS does not read the colour interpretation, and thinks it should be displayed as 3-channel-RGB.

Try this GDAL command line:

```
gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:4326 -a_ullr 67.0 37.5 99.0 27.0 -b 1 -b 1 -b 1 -b 2 -co COMPRESS=LZW  -co ALPHA=YES trans.png transgis.tif
```

to get a working 4-channel RGBA tif file, which is handled by QGIS correctly without manual setting of CRS or style.

Comment: Still same in QGIS: green pixels are all around. Note: I added the source png in 1), and there is the command to reinject georeferencing.

Answer (score 2):

A display fix is to do :

> QGIS > Layers tab : right click > properties > style tab 
>    Band rendering > Rendering type : Singleband grey (choose that!)

[image]

I thereby doesn't really answer the "why" and "how to fix [the file]". If anyone knows....

Comment: See my extended answer. The file is not broken, two-band-files are just not expected by QGIS.