# Creating transparent PNG tiles (for TMS service) from transparent TIFF

Tags: gdal2tiles

I read nice tutorial about making transparent DEM TIFF on ([Creating transparent hillshade?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144535/creating-transparent-hillshade))

My Goal is creating transparent PNG tiles from transparent GeoTIFF
for serving my own TMS map service.

I followed tutorial with SRTM1 N35E128.hgt dem file

1. `gdaldem hillshade c:\n35e128.hgt c:\hillshade.tmp.tif -s 111120 -z 5 -az 315 -alt 60 -compute_edges`
2. `gdal_calc -A c:\hillshade.tmp.tif --outfile=c:\opacity.tif --calc="255-A"`
3. `gdalbuildvrt -separate c:\final.vrt c:\hillshade.tmp.tif c:\opacity.tif`
4. `gdal_translate -of Gtiff c:\final.vrt c:\final.tif`

[image]

At last I got final.tif (please check attatched file)

----> https://mega.nz/#!2XYhiQoY!YPzrS0Z_9CGvIJIRkkSDlJ5M3biW9gvrGr7SHSNjYnU

[image]

then I execute

`gdal2tiles -z 13 c:\final.tif c:\output`

But output PNG files are not transparent at all.

(`nodata` option or `-a 0,0,0,0` wasn't effective)

And then I open the tif file with glabal mapper and export TMS tiles
(with trnasparent png option checked) but the result was the same.
Just blank area of tile was transparent.

I want transparent tile like this. It's fully transparent.

[image: transparent png tile example]

[image: open with photoshop]

How can I get transparent png tiles (TMS) ?

Comment: Hi, what does TMS means ? You may also check out https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/127928/19460 , which deals with transparencies and "may" give some hints.

Comment: Thanks, Hugolpz. TMS means Tile Map Service.(consist of 256x256 px tiles). I tried transparent tiles with QGIS. Adjusting transparecny of tiff file at layer attribution, and then use qmetatiles plugin. It worked.
But transparency pre-adjusted tiff file can't create transparent tiles with gdal2tiles. I don't know why. sorry for bothering.